# How to use the Whmcs getproducts function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, whmcs

I have a Laravel project using the Whmcs integration. This is how whmcs is used:

```
Whmcs::getproducts([
            'pid' => 1,
        ]);
```

Where can I find the `getproducts` function? I searched the function name, but I couldn't find it in the package.

Comment: can you tell us the library that you used ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such a method. The `WhmcsManager` class has a magic method `__call` that is being used. Any non accessible or not existing method calls will be handled by `__call` which will pass the method name and arguments to the `execute` method, which will make the API call with the `action` parameter set as the method name you called.

[`WhmcsManager@__call`](https://github.com/darthsoup/laravel-whmcs/blob/master/src/WhmcsManager.php#L86)

[`WhmcsManager@execute`](https://github.com/darthsoup/laravel-whmcs/blob/master/src/WhmcsManager.php#L48)

[PHP Manual - Classes and Objects - Method Overloading - `__call`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using this package

https://github.com/darthsoup/laravel-whmcs

It is just wrap for working with WHMCS API.

There is API reference for `GetProducts`

https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/getproducts/

So, as far I understood, you have to just set right name with camel case

```php
Whmcs::GetProducts([
    'pid' => 1,
])
```

Or without magic methods:

```php
$whmcs = app('whmcs');
$whmcs->execute('GetProducts', [
    'pid' => 1,
]);
```